# uicomponent tree memory usage

Tags: ajax, jsf, memory, richfaces, uicomponents

Greetings,

I have rich faces application (3.3.2.SR1). The application uses ModelPanel to view entities. All modal panels are not rendered until I want to show them (rendered = false). Application becomes to be big, and uses a lot relations from one panel to others. All works fine, but it looks like richfaces creates UIComponent tree in memory for all possible cases if component rendred is true or false. When I tried to check memory usage of application (I used YourKit Java Profiler for these needs) I see that it uses a lot of memory for one session.

I am using Facelets together with richfaces and I tried to use

```
<c:if test="rendred condition"... /> content </c:if>
```

It starts to use significantly less memory, but...
when I rerender the area with panel, controls on parent screen are stopped to work. I suspect that it is because of every time when component tree is changed it recreates whole tree, and I have unsynchronized client (html) and server (faces) parts.

Could somebody suggest me the way how to reduce memory usage? I have real problem with it as StandardSession object in HeapMemory uses 60-150Mb. And almost all of this memory used for UIControls.

Example of the problem:

I have page which has references to panel1, panel2, panel3.

Panel is:

```
<rich:modalPanel >
    <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" 
             rendered="#{PanelBeanHolder.renderedViewScreen}">
        <ui:insert name="panelContent" />
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

I am rendering panel only when action for this is performed. And do not want to load the UI controls for output panel until I need it.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I tried to do the following to improve the situation

Configure **number of views in session** inside web.xml with:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>4</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
    <param-value>4</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It has to improve StateHolder object, but it doesn't help a lot. I did measuring and memory usage is grows when these number are grow. But, when i tired to set them to 1,1 - some pages stopped work. Sometimes request is forwarded to the welcome page. 2,2 improved the situation, but the issue with forwarding to welcome pages still happens.

Tried to **use client mode in javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD**. It still uses a lot of memory for UIComponent model. Even if objects are serialised and have to be stored in the form.

Tried to **rewrite stateManager**
in faces.config:

```
<state-manager>org.ajax4jsf.application.CompressAjaxStateManager</state-manager>
```

and rewrite buildViewState and restoreView for compressing the stream. 
It doesn't help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

JSF uses a stateful component tree that is maintained between requests. By default, this is usually maintained in the session. There are features you can use to control this.

**Configure state saving parameters**

There are usually implementation-specific parameters to control the number of views stored in the session - depending on how your application behaves, this might be an easy win.

You can save the state in forms using the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` parameter. However, be aware you're sending more information per request and there are security risks in allowing the client to dictate server-side state (ensure you are happy with how your implementation encrypts this data). You will need to check compatibility with your component libraries (i.e. RichFaces), especially if you're using AJAX.

*JSF 2 uses a new state-saving mechanism that reduces the session overhead; your `faces-config.xml` will need to be updated to the 2.0 version. I believe this idea came from Apache [Trinidad](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/index.html), so you may be able to extract a pre-JSF 2 version from there.*

**Do your own state saving and/or view creation**

Implementing your own [`StateManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/StateManager.html) and/or [`ViewHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html) lets you take programmatic control over how views are handled. For example, you could write a `StateManager` that persisted views to a database (with appropriate time-out and clean-up).

**Use component binding and transient controls**

You can take programmatic control over how components are created. From the spec on binding:

> - When a component instance is first created (typically by virtue of being referenced by a `UIComponentELTag` in a JSP page), the JSF implementation will retrieve the `ValueExpression` for the name binding, and call `getValue()` on it. If this call returns a non-null `UIComponent` value (because the JavaBean programmatically instantiated and configured a component already), that instance will be added to the component tree that is being created. If the call returns null, a new component instance will be created, added to the component tree, and `setValue()` will be called on the `ValueExpression` (which will cause the property on the JavaBean to be set to the newly created component instance).
> - When a component tree is recreated during the Restore View phase of the request processing lifecycle, for each component that has a `ValueExpression` associated with the name “binding”, `setValue()` will be called on it, passing the recreated component instance.

You could probably use this with the [transient](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/StateHolder.html#setTransient%28boolean%29) property on children to control programmatically control creation/destruction of child components. This is manual and a bit messy, but might work in extreme cases.

*I'm sure this isn't an exhaustive list.*

Comment: +1 It's a good explanation. Especially JSF 2 seems be a rather huge win with the partial state saving feature. JSF 2 also greatly simplified the API for handling state when writing your own component (this doesn't help the TS of course). I also want to add that implementing your own StateManager is really an advanced topic and should maybe not be done lightheartedly unless you feel really comfortable with the JSF API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added more information to my post, which should to describe more details based on my investigation.